# Button set as disabled doesn't behave as the selector says (Android)

Tags: android, android-selector

I have always had trouble with Android selectors, and I can't understand how to make this work.
I have a button called "Completed" which is grey and disabled until you have indeed completed everything you need to, then it turns blue. There's no problem doing this programmatically, however I feel like using an xml drawable is more appropriate. The point is that if I use it, the button is blue until I don't set it enabled(false) (as if it's choosing the last option in the drawable file), and then it doesn't change its appearance, even though I set it enabled(true) (and it is indeed enabled).

If I use android:theme instead of style, the button doesn't have any of my appearances (it is light grey, something I never set) until I set it disabled (and then doesn't change appearance).

This is my button:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/completed"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/half_spacing"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_spacing"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_spacing"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_spacing"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_spacing"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_spacing"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/half_spacing"
        android:text="@string/completed"/>
```

This is my styles.xml:

```
<style name="MyButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/my_button</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/half_spacing</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/default_spacing</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/default_spacing</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/half_spacing</item>
</style>
```

My drawable:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_button_enabled"
          android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_button_disabled"
          android:state_enabled="false"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_button_enabled"/>
</selector>
```

Drawable for button enabled:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
      android:state_pressed="true"/>

<item android:drawable="@color/colorAccent"/>
</selector>
```

Drawable for button disabled:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/dark_grey"
          android:state_pressed="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@color/grey"/>
</selector>
```

The code (as you can see, I have commented the part where I set the background dynamically):

```
if (mCurrentPosition == mCurrentDocument.getDocumentSections().size() - 1) {
            mCompleted.setEnabled(true);
//            mCompleted.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.colorAccent));
        } else {
            mCompleted.setEnabled(false);
//            mCompleted.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.grey));
        }
```

I have tried pretty much everything I could find, I am really out of ideas.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried directly mean without style?

Comment: post your full activity code, i think that problem is with the scope of "mCompleted"

Comment: What do you mean "directly"?
If you mean programmatically then yes, it's commented in the code. If you don't mean this then I am sorry but I don't know how you can change appearance based on state without selectors.

Comment: did you tried `mCompleted.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.desired_drawable));`

Comment: @AkshayTilekar you were right, while I was pasting the code here I noticed that there was a line where I set the background color as grey programmatically which wasn't commented out. This probably happened in merging since I'm not the only one working on this project...now it works and I feel a little bit stupid. Thank you anyway!!

Comment: @SaraSeward you are welcome :)

Comment: can you post your answer below so that seekers can come to know what happens actually

Comment: Actually my answer is that I hadl left mCompleted.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.grey)); in the onCreate...so I suppose that colors set in the activity /fragment/programmatically > colors set in the layout xml > colors set in the style (like in HTML where CSS can be overridden) :)